# Add Input Field to Page Block

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to create a table with input text fields for the row data.The table is displaying but I cannot add the input data, the input text field isn't active.

Please kindly assist me:

**Visual force Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" controller="addMultipleIPV4Extension">
<apex:form id="formId">
<apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listIPV4}" var="b" >
<apex:column headerValue="Network" value="{!b.Network}"  >
   </apex:column> <apex:inputtext /> 
<apex:column headerValue="Size" value="{!b.Size}" ></apex:column>
   <apex:column headerValue="Assigned By" value="{!b.AssignedBy}">
   </apex:column> <apex:inputtext /> 
<apex:column headerValue="Percentage" value="{!b.Network}">
   </apex:column> <apex:inputtext />       
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton value="Add another record" action="{!addIPV4}"     rerender="pageBlock" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class addMultipleIPV4Extension {
public list<myWrapper> listIPV4{get;set;}
Public myWrapper bk ;
public addMultipleIPV4Extension () {
    myWrapper wrap = new myWrapper();
    listIPV4= new list<myWrapper> ();
    listIPV4.add(wrap);
}
public void addIPV4(){
    myWrapper wrap1 = new myWrapper();
    listIPV4.add(wrap1);
}
   public void saveIPV4Records(){
   }
   class myWrapper {
       public String Network{get;set;}
       public String Size{get;set;}
       public String AssignedBy{get;set;}
       public String PercentageInUse{get;set;}
    } 
}
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your fields to your inputtext tags, such as `<apex:inputtext value="{!b.size}" />`

Also, I assume you have the table embedded in apex:form tags, and likely want to place the inputtext tags inside the column tags.